# Any way to pack Sencha Touch app as Google Chrome packaged app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-chrome-extension, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch app. Now there is a need to distribute it as Google Chrome app. I wrapped a ST production build as Google Chrome extension and got several error messages in console:

1. index.html has inline script (ST microloader injects it), but inline scripts are not allowed in Google Chrome apps. This seems can be fixed by moving the script in a separate file. Is there a better workaround?
2. window.localStorage is not available, I'm forced to use chrome.storage but the app actively uses localStorage. localStorage is sync, chrome.storage is async. Do I need to write own ST adapter to use chrome.storage or is there better way doing this? Existing libraries?
3. EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". I was unable to find the exact source of this issue...
4. I guess I will get more other issues, when these ones will be fixed and the app can proceed next...

The main question is can Sencha Touch (not ExtJS) be used for Google Chrome apps or it's definitely wrong and not supposed to? Do I need to stop here if Sencha Touch is just bad solution for Google Chrome apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. a separate js file is the best solution otherwise you'll have [to sandbox the entire page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox):

   > You can’t use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. [...] Chrome extensions will let you relax the default Content Security Policy; **Chrome Apps won’t.**
2. you can make it even better than `localStorage` by making a `prefs` wrapper this way:

   - load the settings from `chrome.storage` at the app start into an internal object
   - watch for subsequent dynamic changes in [chrome.storage.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#event-onChanged) event listener that will update the internal object and broadcast a `settingChanged` event to your app.
   - in `prefs.set` method put the value both into the internal object and `chrome.storage`.
3. there must be `eval` in some of the js libs you use. The best solution is too refactor the code to get rid of `eval`, otherwise sandbox the page, see [Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval)

---

I haven't used Sencha Touch so I can't say if it's easy to modify it or is it worth the effort.
Try asking on their support forum too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I searched for eval and seems ST framework is using it across many components, thus I can not ged rid of eval. If I sandbox the app I won't be able use chrome api, but I need it for push notification, storage and probably some more things. I will wait for other answers that might give me more related info for Sencha Touch / Chrome apps compatibility and probably some ready-to-go solutions. If no, I will mark your post as an accepted answer.

Comment: @terreb, put sencha into a sandboxed frame on the normal page and separate the sencha-related logic from the main logic that can use chrome API, see [an example for SQL.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30165546/3959875).